# Is it possible to install Mac OS X Server on a Mac Mini without hacking it?

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server, update, automatic-updates

I'd like to have a Software Update Server (SUS) for my clients.

Since this service would not be critical, redundancy and availability are not an issue for me.

Given the fact that SUS is only available on Mac OS X Server (I'd be happy to be denied), I'm asking if it is technically possible to install Mac OS X Server on this HW without the need for any particular hack.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, according to [apple themselves](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/servers-made-easy.html) you can run OSX server on a mac pro, iMac or Mac Mini. So it should just work.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, its perfectly possible to install Mac OSX Server on a Mac Mini, although performance may not be stellar.

The minimum system requirements advertised for OS X 10.5 Server are:

- Mac server or desktop computer with an Intel, PowerPC G5, or PowerPC G4 (867MHz or faster) processor
- 1 GB of RAM
- 20 GB of available disk space

A recent Mac Mini will fulfill all of those.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to note however, that while OSX Server 10.5 is still the primary Apple server OS, your Mac Mini **is not** supported by Apple.

While the server operating system will run with little to no problem, should you require any support from Apple, they will hang up on you (metaphorically) when you tell them what it's running on.

Official support for the Mac Mini hardware doesn't come till September when OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard server is release.

Comment: Sorry, but -1 as this is not true. You get a few months of phone support when you purchase OS X Server, unless it's running on an unsupported Mac (i.e.: a notebook or an older Mac that doesn't meet the minimum system requirements) in which case it doesn't matter if you upgrade or not. A newer Mac Mini should be supported.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, there is now a version of the mac mini shipping with OS X Server:

http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MC408LL/A?mco=MTM3NTAyODU

You can also run OS X Server in a VM from VMware's products.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. And it is cheaper than the one I bought as it is comprehensive of the OSXServer license.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (2011) the default line that comes with OS X Server installed is the Mac Mini. I use it as a simple production server and have had no issues.